# How to connect to more than 7 Bluetooth Devices

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know that **i cannot establish an active connection with more than 7 devices**.
But there must be a way to at least **read the specific characteristic** that i need and disconnect afterwards! I tried to do that but for my purposes it takes too much time to:

a) establish the connection and

b) disconnect afterwards. (Especially as there is no explicit quick way to disconnect apart from dispose and nullify!)

Does anyone have experience with that or did something similar?

I also heard about Park-Mode that would allow the device to stay synchronized and reestablish connection more quickly. But it seems i cannot put the device in this mode remotely (from WPF-App)...

Answer (score 1):

The Bluetooth Specification (4.1) limits you to 7 concurrent connections as a Central and 1 as a Peripheral.

There's no getting around that and still keeping to the 4.1 specification. I believe 4.2 allows more concurrent connections.

You can Connect/Discover/Read Characteristics/Disconnect, and do that pretty quickly, but you can't get around that limitation. future versions of the spec may allow it, but whatever chip you're using will have to support that new spec.

Another thing to do is use the Custom Data section of the Advertising Data to send out 20 bytes of Custom data.  You can compact a lot into 20 bytes, depending on your usecase.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So your saying I could just listen to the advertisment and not connect at all/Fetching the data just by beeing coupled?

Comment: @laurence it depends; if you control both ends, yes. If not, then you'll have to connect, discover/read specific characteristic, disconnect, and repeat.